# How should I name a Java method that needs a subchapter form?

Tags: java, naming-conventions

I need to implement a set of rules in a validation class. Each rule needs to be checked in its own method (because of the ability to configure which rules should be checked). The problem is that the rule names come from an official entity(naming must be preserved) which defined them in the format:

Rule 1.1
Rule 1.2
Rule 1.3
...
Rule 2.29

Currently I am using a format like **testRule1_1()** , but it does not comply to the official Java naming conventions. How could this be renamed to comply?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: can't u just use a `switch`statement?

Comment: Rule1sect1, Rule1sub1?

Comment: Rule0101, RuleCh1Sect1, Rule1x1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your goal should not be to slavishly follow naming conventions, but to remember their original purpose. The official Java naming conventions are designed to (1) make code more readable, and (2) prevent naming conflicts (e.g., between class and method names). If the conventions are counterproductive to achieving those purposes, it's correct to ignore them. They are only recommendations and emphatically not rules, and even in the standard API the naming conventions are sometimes (deliberately) ignored.

The method name `testRule1_1()` is unquestionably legal in the Java language, and is readable, and so it is not wrong to use it. Besides, I'm not convinced it *is* against convention. I don't recall ever seeing written guidance about how to separate numbers in a method name, but you would surely not be the first person to use an underscore.

Just as an opinion, I think `testRule1_1()` is fine, but I most prefer `testRule1x1()` as suggested by Joop Eggen in the comments above. Any other word inserted between the numbers as a spacer seems like an unsound sacrifice of brevity, but a simple `x` is short, and compared to an underscore it is quick to mentally read out.

Comment: Or, as one famous pirate said, _the code_ (in this case the naming conventions) _is more what you'd call "guidelines" than actual rules_. :-)

Comment: Thank you for your opinions. I just wanted to check if the community has the same viewpoint on the matter as myself. I know that these are just guidelines, but nevertheless I would like for my code to adhere as much as possible to the conventions since it will treat official requirements. As the standard suggests to avoid underscores and numbers in method names, i've searched online a bit about alternatives, but came out short.